# Fill in placeholder in a variable

Tags: python

How can I fill in a placeholder in a string from another variable.

```
value = 'john'
my_str = 'src/edu/{value}/obj.txt'
```

Required output:

```
'src/edu/john/obj.txt'
```

The value 'john' is replaced in the output string.

I tried `eval()` but didn't work.